# jQuery automate function call

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

How do I call a given function every X seconds?

In this case, I made a function that scrolls some images. I want the image to change based on a given interval of time, for example, every 5 seconds, but I really have no idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for jQuery here, plain JavaScript using [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval) will do:

```
function myFunctionName() {
  //change image here
}
setInterval(myFunctionName, 5000);
```

Or the anonymous version:

```
setInterval(function () {
  //change image here
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
setInterval(function, Xseconds);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) to do it for you, there is a plugin, [jquery.cycle.all](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/). This will make creating the transition very easy. If you're using jQuery already, then it might be a good fit. Otherwise, the `setInterval` is easy to work with that other posters already mentioned.